Python pymysql updates
Is it a good idea to check if any changes will happen before attempting a commit to the database with python's pymysql when a large number of updates will potentially happen while looping through values to query or is it a relative waste of time?
So instead of doing something like this:
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(xxxx)
cur = db.cursor()

for items in list:
    sql = "update TABLE set A = %s where B = %s"
    params = [items[0], items[1]]
    cur.execute(sql, params)
    db.commit()

Doing something like this:
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(xxxx)
cur = db.cursor()

for items in list:
    sql = "update TABLE set A = %s where B = %s"
    params = [items[0], items[1]]
    affected_rows = cur.execute(sql, params)

    if affected_rows > 0:
        db.commit()

